# Automatically start a python service on raspbian with fault tolerance

Tags: python, service, raspbian

I write a simple linux python service. The service responds to the following commands: [python service.py start] [python service.py stop] [python service.py restart]

Now I want that the service automatically start with the raspberry and I want that it automatically restart in case of fault. 
The raspberry runs the raspbian OS (Debian based).

I read that I have to write a /etc/init.d script in order to start the service.py with the raspberry and than I have to put a rule in /etc/inittab in order to restart the service.py in case of fault.

Is it the right way? Any suggestion?

Comment: i just want to ask a small question i always have when i see questions like this: why run python in embedded system?

Comment: it is for a research project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [upstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto):

A very basic example would be something  like the following `/etc/init/service.conf`:

```
start on startup

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

exec python service.py start
```

All the info you need is in the link above and [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id68)

Answer (score 1):

why not just make

## wrapper.py

```
while True:
    os.system("python my_service.py")
```

its probably not "the right way"

but it is a pretty easy way ...